# How to gather/verify certificate data with limited information (Issuer, Serial, CN)

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates

I've been included in an analysis project or "cleaning up" of information which includes fields from certificates. I don't know how to access the actual certificates. I'd like to learn as much as I can about how/what can be verified in relation to a certificate. (I'm not doing security work, I just need to read the information.)

I have several spreadsheets with information including certificate data, all different sources with different fields. I'm trying to consolidate this information into a single table with as much verified as possible. Most records have Control Name, Serial Number, URL, etc., but based on the inconsistencies throughout other fields I think wrong or incomplete data has been added.

For instance, I'd like to verify that the expiration date on a spreadsheet is what is actually on the certificate. It also looks like one of the spreadsheets converted long serial numbers into a numeric data type, truncating(all 0's) the last half of the SN. Is there a way to look up all of a CN's certificates issued by a CA?

I'm very new to this, any tips would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: So you can't access the certificates but want to validate them? I don't really understand your question. For example, what do you mean by "_Is there a way to look up all of a CN's certificates issued by a CA?_"

Comment: The certificates are used in their respective environments and processes. What I'd like to do is what can be done [with some verisign certs here](https://securitycenter.verisign.com/celp/enroll/outsideSearch?application_locale=VRSN_US). Sorry if CN isn't the right identifier. If I have a record with an issuer, "VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA" and client listed "The Home Depot, Inc." Is there a method for asking whatever server verisign is on, Do you have a certificate for "The Home Depot, Inc.". If there is, can I get information about that certificate like validity dates, city, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general, public way I know of.

However, you might be able to get in touch with some CAs and do a research cooperation, but I doubt it. Handing out certificates to somebody else could be a privacy concern. And there's no chance you'll get certificates from *all* the CAs out there.

What you *can* do is obtain the certificates when they are used for publicly available services. For example if a certificate is issued to `mail.example.com` you could try to establish a TLS session to the host. You may have to try different ports, and maybe you are lucky and the host presents the certificate you are looking for.